# Correct way for excluding constraints based on index

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Assume the following constraint:

```
@constraint(model, [i=1:5,j=1:5], a[i] <= b[j])
```

How do I exclude constraint where `i == j` from the above? This is simple to do in AMPL but I can't find any similar syntax in JuMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@constraint(model, [i=1:5, j=1:5; i != j], a[i] <= b[j])`

Comment: Thank you, it works. There is no mention of this syntax in [JuMP documentation](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refexpr.html#methods). You could improve this answer (+1) by adding how you knew this was possible or giving some reference to this specific syntax form.

Comment: I knew this was possible because I created the syntax, but you're correct that it's not well documented. It's mentioned for [variables](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/refvariable.html#constructors) but also applies more generally. Will be addressed in the upcoming rewrite of the documentation.